# Add slideshow option to 'link image to' in Views

Tags: 7, media, views

I have created a View that displays images uploaded on my website as thumbnails and in a grid style. However when I click on an image I would like some slideshow function to show so the user can click 'left' and 'right' to scroll through the images.
How can I add this functionality to 'the Link Image to' setting?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have a Gallery or Slideshow working (otherwise check other modules, e.g. [Juicebox](https://www.drupal.org/project/juicebox)). If you want the image to link to a specific path you need to choose the option **Rewrite Results** > **Output this field as a link**. You can use tokens if you want to change this path dynamically according to other fields in the View.

[image]